# Unable to retrieve simultaneous number of touches

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

In my `UIView` subclass I have this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet*) touches withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location  = [touch locationInView: self];
    NSLog(@"touches count: %i",[touches count]); //always shows 1
}
```

No matter how many fingers I touch the screen with, I only get "1" as the output. I also added the above to `touchesMoved` with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled the multitouch option?

```
[(your uiview) setMultiTouchEnabled:YES];
```

This is by default false, that will translate all touches on your view to one single touch in the middle of all other touches.

Setting it to `YES` will make your view recieve one touch event for each finger (or pen) on screen

Comment: And the winner goes to the first responder, thanks. This is what I was missing. I will accept this answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: By the way, with "first responder," there was no pun intended!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a "multiple touch enabled" checkbox in interface builder... And also a corresponding property you can set.